# How to redirect to new page of app after modification of document

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a page that I print a DIV from using the following script...

```
function printReceiptDiv() {
            var divElements;
            if (vm.isDLR) {
                divElements = document.getElementById("DLRreportContent").innerHTML;
            } else {
                divElements = document.getElementById("SHDRreportContent").innerHTML;
            }
            var oldPage = document.body.innerHTML;
            if (vm.isDLR) {
                document.body.innerHTML = '<html><head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="content/css/receiptprint.css"><title></title></head><body>' + divElements + '</body>';
            } else {
                document.body.innerHTML = '<html><head><title></title></head><body>' + divElements + '</body>';
            }

            window.print();
            document.body.innerHTML = oldPage;
```

The original page has some buttons on it (above the DIV I am printing).  I either need to rewire those buttons so they are active or preferably redirect to the home page.  (Home page is #)
I have tried several methods found in various posts on here such as

`document.location("#");`

`window.location("#");`

`$location.path = "#";`

and  a few others all without success.

The application uses simple JavaScript, Angular, Bootstrap, and JQuery.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried? window.location.assign("#");

Comment: If you want to go to homepage ('#') on a button click, try `location.href='#'` on the `onclick` of the button.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using an `onclick` listener on your buttons with individual pages set as `display:hidden` when not active and `display:block` when you want them loaded